# CSVデータを抽出【空白除外】、データ加工について

Tags: python, csv

やりたいこと：
csvファイルのデータを抽出し、B列に空白があれば除外した後に文字列を追加します。

CSVのデータ

```
A       B      C       D
アメリカ  1234   空白    ワシントン
カナダ　　空白　 バンクーバー空白
日本    2345　　東京     空白
イタリア　 空白　　空白     空白
```

①抽出したいデータ下記のように表示します。

```
1234
2345
```

②最終的にこちらの形式でデータを加工して表示したいです。

```
Number/1234
Number/2345
```

こちらのコードを記載しましたが下記のように表示されます。

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

#CSVファイルの読み込み
df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')

#B列だけ読み込み
df_i =  df1[["B"]] 

#空白を除外
df_i = df1[df1["B"].str.contains("",na=False)]

#1行ごとをループさせて空白を含まない
for j in range(len(df_i)):
 a =''.join([f"{data}"for column,data in df_i.iloc[j].iteritems()])

 s ='Number/'+a
 print(s)
```

出力結果

```
print(s)

Number/アメリカ1234nanワシントンnan....
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: CSVと書かれていますがデータにはカンマが含まれておらず、これだと「列データの区切りの空白」なのか、「空データを表す空白」なのかの見分けが付かない気がします。

Comment: 一応、デリミタの連続を許した character-separated values とは言えそうです、が、「空白」の意味が曖昧というのはその通りですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) の `converters` keyword を使う方法です。

```py
import pandas as pd

s = '\n'.join(filter(None,
  pd.read_csv(
    'test.csv',
    usecols=['B'], encoding='utf_8_sig', squeeze=True,
    converters={
      'B': lambda x: 'Number/'+x if x else x
    })))

print(s)
=>
Number/1234
Number/2345
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらシンプルでしたので使わせていただきます。因みにlambdaはどのように使えますか

Answer (score 2):

CSVということですが, CSVの形式ではないので, CSVの間違いなのかコードの問題なのか分かりません。
とりあえず以下のような CSVを用意して試してみました

```
A,B,C,D
アメリカ,1234,,ワシントン
カナダ,,バンクーバー,
日本,2345,東京,
イタリア,
```

プログラムはこんな感じ

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(csvf)
for c in df.B.dropna():
  print(f'Number/{int(c)}')
```

以下出力

```
Number/1234
Number/2345
```

Comment: CSVがこれで構わなければ 解説続けることも可能だけど, この CSVは違うというなら, 追加する予定の説明が無駄になるので, ここまでで

Comment: ＠oriri
ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらも試してみます。

Answer (score 2):

元のデータが全角空白や半角空白で区切られています。
データを修正することが、一番優先されるでしょう。

仮に半角空白区切りなら、

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv',delim_whitespace=True)
```

タブ区切りなら、

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimiter='\t')
```

といった感じで、カンマ区切り（csv)以外も、自分が指定して、読み込めるようにはなっています。
ただ例にあるようなデータのように、区切り文字が全角半角の空白が混在する環境までは、正しく動作することは期待できないのです。
自分で読み込み部分を実装するか、元のデータを修正してから作業するか、ということになります。
それによって、アドバイスも変わってきます。

下記のスクリプトは、半角、全角の空白をどちらも区切り文字とみなしカンマ(,)に置き換えます。
また'空白'という２文字が必要なデータなのか不明ですが、取り除く処理も追加しています。
項目数やデータの中身、の関係で、そのまま残す必要があるなら残すで良いかと思います。

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys

#全角、半角空白を置き換えるためのパターン
#どんな環境でも動くかは、把握できかねます。
pattern=re.compile(r'[ 　]+')
#'空白'という文字列を削除するためのパターン
pattern2=re.compile(r'空白')

#第一引数のファイル名を変換します。
ifile=sys.argv[1]

#新しいファイル名を元のファイル名に-to-csv.csvに変換します。元のファイル名の拡張子は消しません。
#ファイル名が衝突した場合は上書きされます。
#改行コードが特殊なケースは想定しません。

ofile=open(ifile+'-to-csv.csv','tw')
with open(ifile,'tr') as fin:
    #一行ずつ処理します。
    for iline in fin:
        #全角空白、半角空白をカンマに置き換える。
        #動作保証はできません。
        buf=pattern.sub(',',iline)
        #さらに空白、という文字列を取り除く。不要な処理なら削除してください。
        buf=pattern2.sub('',buf)
        #ファイルへの書き込み
        ofile.write(buf)
    ofile.close()
```

Comment: 下記の処理ですが、除外なら~が必要ではありませんか？↲
```↲
#空白を除外↲
df_i = df1[~df1["B"].str.contains("",na=False)]↲
```↲

Comment: お世話になっております。
ご回答ありがとうございます。~確かに反転させて必要でしたね